# MQTT mosquitto - Implementing websocket in javascript using mqttws31.js

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

Implementing a websocket using MQTT with mosquitto broker using javascript by including mqttws32.js file.

Mosquitto version: 1.4.9

On start I got:

```
rohan@rohan-PC:~$ mosquitto
1470241326: mosquitto version 1.4.9 (build date Fri, 03 Jun 2016 09:22:47 +0100) starting
1470241326: Using default config.
1470241326: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1470241326: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

As latest version of mosquitto supports Web socket.

I'm using following code:

```
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost", 1883, "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
```

Getting error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1883/mqtt' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I listener i got:

```
1470241581: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
1470241581: Socket error on client &lt;unknown&gt;, disconnecting.
```

After searching I found a solution to add following line to mosquitto.conf file

```
listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

I changed to port to 1884 but still getting the same error.

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you using? Also please update the question with the mosquitto output on startup so we can see that the listeners are set up properly

Comment: rohan@rohan-PC:~$ mosquitto
1470241326: mosquitto version 1.4.9 (build date Fri, 03 Jun 2016 09:22:47 +0100) starting
1470241326: Using default config.
1470241326: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1470241326: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.

Comment: Edit the question, don't try and post output as comments

Comment: Done.. added output at startup and also after connection with web socket

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mosquitto does not have a default config file location so you need to actually specify it on the command line

```
$ mosquitto -c /path/to/mosquitto.conf
```

The config file also should have an extra line in it if you still want to listen on 1883 for native MQTT connections as well as websockets on 1884

```
port 1883

listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

That should get you a functioning broker that is actually listening for MQTT over Websockets on port 1884

Comment: Thank u very very much...
Its working perfectly..
I was sick of searching but found nothing
If it was possible i had upvoted it for 100 times 
But sorry its not possible for me..

Again thanks a lot man..